# fmin_ncg not returning an optimized result

Tags: python, machine-learning, octave, jupyter, logistic-regression

I am trying to use fmin_ncg for minimizing my cost function. But, the results that I get back are not minimized. I get the same result I would get without advanced optimization. I know for a fact that it can further be minimized.

PS. I am trying to code assignment 2 of the [Coursera's ML course](https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning).

My cost fn:

```
def costFn(theta, X, y, m, lam):
    h = sigmoid(X.dot(theta))
    theta0 = theta
    J = 1 / m * np.sum((-(y * np.log(h))) - ((1-y) * np.log(1-h))) + (lam/(2*m) * theta0.T.dot(theta0))
    return J.flatten()
```

X would look something like this:

```
[[  1.00000000e+00   5.12670000e-02   6.99560000e-01 ...,   6.29470940e-04
8.58939846e-03   1.17205992e-01]
 [  1.00000000e+00  -9.27420000e-02   6.84940000e-01 ...,   1.89305413e-03
   -1.39810280e-02   1.03255971e-01]
 [  1.00000000e+00  -2.13710000e-01   6.92250000e-01 ...,   1.04882142e-02
   -3.39734512e-02   1.10046893e-01]
 ..., 
 [  1.00000000e+00  -4.84450000e-01   9.99270000e-01 ...,   2.34007252e-01
   -4.82684337e-01   9.95627986e-01]
 ....
```

Y is a bunch of 0s and 1s

```
[[1]
[1]
[1]
[1]
...
[0]
[0]]

X.shape = (118, 28)
y.shape = (118, 1)
```

My grad function:

```
def grad(theta, X, y, m, lam):
    h = sigmoid(X.dot(theta))
    theta0 = initial_theta
    gg = 1.0 / m * ((X.T.dot(h-y)) + (lam * theta0))
    return gg.flatten()
```

Using just my costFn and grad, I get the following:

```
Cost at initial theta (zeros): 0.69314718056
```

With fmin_ncg:

```
xopt = fmin_ncg(costFn, fprime=grad, x0=initial_theta, args=(X, y, m, lam), maxiter=400, disp=True, full_output=True )
```

I get:

```
Optimization terminated successfully.
     Current function value: 0.693147
     Iterations: 1
     Function evaluations: 2
     Gradient evaluations: 4
     Hessian evaluations: 0
```

Using octave, my J after advanced optimization should be:

```
 0.52900
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

EDIT:
I got my optimization to work:

```
y1 = y.flatten()
Result = op.minimize(fun = costFn, 
                x0 = initial_theta, 
                args = (X, y1, m, lam),
                method = 'CG',
                options={'disp': True})
```

I get the costFn to be 0.52900, which is what I expected.

But the values of 'theta' are a bit off that the accuracy is only 42%. It's supposed to be 83%.

The values of theta I got:

```
[ 1.14227089  0.60130664  1.16707559 -1.87187892 -0.91534354 -1.26956697
0.12663015 -0.36875537 -0.34522652 -0.17363325 -1.42401493 -0.04872243
-0.60650726 -0.269242   -1.1631064  -0.24319088 -0.20711764 -0.04333854
-0.28026111 -0.28693582 -0.46918892 -1.03640373  0.02909611 -0.29266766
 0.01725324 -0.32899144 -0.13795701 -0.93215664]
```

The actual values:

```
[1.273005 0.624876 1.177376 -2.020142 -0.912616 -1.429907 0.125668 -0.368551
-0.360033 -0.171068 -1.460894 -0.052499 -0.618889 -0.273745 -1.192301 
-0.240993 -0.207934 -0.047224 -0.278327 -0.296602 -0.453957 -1.045511 
0.026463 -0.294330 0.014381 -0.328703 -0.143796 -0.924883]
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all your gradient is invalid

```
def grad(theta, X, y, m, lam):
    h = sigmoid(X.dot(initial_theta))
    theta0 = initial_theta
    gg = 1 / m * ((X.T.dot(h-y)) + (lam * theta0))
    return gg.flatten()
```

this function **never uses theta**, you put `initial_theta` instead, which is incorrect.

Similar error in the cost

```
def costFn(theta, X, y, m, lam):
    h = sigmoid(X.dot(initial_theta))
    theta0 = theta
    J = 1 / m * np.sum((-(y * np.log(h))) - ((1-y) * np.log(1-h))) + (lam/(2*m) * theta0.T.dot(theta0))
    return J.flatten()
```

you have some odd mix of `theta` and `initial_theta`, which also does not make sense, there should be only `theta` inside. As a side note - there should be no need for flattening, your cost function should be **a scalar**, thus if you have to flatten - something is wrong in your computations.

Also worth checking - what is your `m`? If it is an integer, and you are using python 2.X, then `1 / m` equals **zero**, since it is **integer division**. You should do `1.0 / m` instead. (in both functions)

Comment: I corrected the grad() and constFn() to have 'theta' and not 'initial_theta'. I managed to get the optimization to return a optimized costfn, but the values of theta that it returns are a bit off. I am supposed to get an accuracy of 83% but instead I am only getting 42%! See my edit! @lejlot